# Why the print new line doesnt work?

Tags: java

I started to learn Java and I build this code from a book. This is the code in Java:

```
public class MyFirstApp {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int x = 1;
        while (x<3){
            System.out.print("Doo"+x);
            System.out.print("Bee");
            x=x+1;
        }
        if (x==3){
            System.out.println("Do"+x);
        }
    }
}
```

Why the output is:

```
Doo1BeeDoo2BeeDo3
```

instead of

```
Doo1BeeDoo2Bee
Do3
```

Comment: First of all do one thing read the official docs for both the method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29 Use this link for reading about print stream methods. You will be getting your solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the *last* call is to `println`... and `println` adds a newline at the *end* of what it's printing. Do if you want a newline *before* the final `Do3` you'd want something like:

```
if (x==3){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Do"+x);
}
```

(It's not really clear why the check is in there at all. `x` is bound to be 3.)

Answer (score 3):

you're printing line break *after* the Do3. println adds the line break after the message, not before.

See the documentation of [println()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29):

> Prints a String and then terminate the line. This method behaves as
>   though it invokes print(String) and then println().

If you want, try

```
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Do"+x);
```

or

```
System.out.println("\nDo"+x);
```

in your last if to get it printed on its own line.

Answer (score 2):

Because `println()` moves to a new line *after* printing its argument, which in this case is at the very end of the output.

Answer (score 1):

you're printin line break after the Do3.

try this

```
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Do"+x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `System.out.print()` will print to `System.out` without a new line . `System.out.println()` shifts to new line after printing the string and not before it .